# Enabling wildcard subdomains for all domains on cPanel

Tags: apache, cpanel, httpd.conf

I've hired a new VPS and have root access. Now i want to configure this VPS to my likelings. 
I know how to enable wildcard subdomains for one host, but i want to do this for **ALL domains** at once on the server.
Any idea's?

Could something like this work:

```
<VirtualHost *>
    ServerAlias *.*
</VirtualHost>
```

DNS is allready set up.

Comment: I don't think that would work no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin postmaster@dummy-host.localhost
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/
    ServerName dummy-host.localhost
    ServerAlias www.dummy-host.localhost
    ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host.localhost-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/dummy-host.localhost-access.log" combined
</VirtualHost>
```

This is apache default virtual host. It means **all**  requests to server that have not been configured yet, will use this as virtual host. So you need to copy what I wrote. just edit values according to your server config.